# Fix an underfill with an equation in display mode

Tags: equations, breqn, hfill, underfull

I have a paragraph with an equation in display mode. I would like to continue the paragraph under the equation, but I get an underfill issue. If I add \hfill, the additional text is part of a new paragraph, which I don't want. Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

%================%
%  New Commands  %
%================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}\label{eq:cost}
J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\left[(\gamma_i(t_f) - \overline{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \overline{\sigma}_f)^2\right],
\end{dmath} where $\overline{\gamma}_f$ and $\overline{\sigma}_f$ are shorthand for mean flight-path elevation and heading angles, respectively.

\end{document}
```

How do I fix this issue? I would like my paper to be well formatted with a common column width.

Comment: Off-topic: the `\displaystyle` directive between `:=` and `\sum` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you get, which is indeed unacceptable.

[image]

Note that `breqn` doesn't know about `:=`.

If you're striving for good typesetting, you shouldn't use `breqn` that does its best to split long formulas, but rarely succeeds in doing good.

Rather, you should use a Times-based math font, in order to complement the Times text font used by `IEEEtran`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

%================%
%  New Commands  %
%================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cost}
J[\xb(\,{\cdot}\,),t_f] :=
\sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i
  [(\gamma_i(t_f) - \bar{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \bar{\sigma}_f)^2],
\end{equation}
where $\bar{\gamma}_f$ and $\bar{\sigma}_f$ are shorthand for
mean flight-path elevation and heading angles, respectively.

\end{document}
```

Note the omission of `\left` and `\right` and the substitution of `\overline` with `\bar`.

The `\displaystyle` declaration is not needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as answer)

I am unable to generate an "underfull \hbox" warning if I compile your code with the `article` document class at its default settings. Hence, please provide more information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ, which font and font size do you use, and how wide is the text block?

I can see no reason for employing a `dmath` environment for the displayed equation at hand; I'd rather employ a basic `equation` environment. I'd also load the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and use its `\coloneqq` macro to typeset the ":=" symbol. Finally, consider using `\bar` instead of `\overline` to "decorate" `\gamma` and `\sigma`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, % for '\coloneqq' macro
            amsthm, 
            amssymb} % 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically

% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cost}
J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] \coloneqq  \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}} w_i
\bigl[ (\gamma_i(t_f) - \bar{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \bar{\sigma}_f)^2 \bigr]\,,
\end{equation} 
where $\bar{\gamma}_f$ and $\bar{\sigma}_f$ are shorthand for mean flight-path elevation and heading angles, respectively.

\end{document}
```